# Complex SQL query to generate percentage reports in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table.

| Column name | Data Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | uuid |
| origin | uuid |
| type | varchar(31) |
| date | timestamp |

Example records:

| id | origin | type | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1111 | A | 2021-11-09 10:01:31.001 |
| 2 | 1111 | A | 2021-11-08 03:02:22.020 |
| 3 | 1111 | B | 2021-10-01 11:03:13.003 |
| 4 | 2222 | A | 2021-11-07 13:04:54.040 |
| 5 | 3333 | B | 2021-11-09 20:05:45.005 |
| 6 | 3333 | B | 2021-11-08 21:06:36.060 |
| 7 | 3333 | B | 2021-11-08 00:07:27.700 |

I'd like to make a SQL query that generates a report showing the percentage of `origin`s that has each `type`, or both, in the last 7 days (`date` column). There are several records for the same `origin`.

Desired example result:

| PercentageOfOriginThatHasTypeAInLast7Days | PercentageOfOriginThatHasTypeBInLast7Days | PercentageOfOriginThatHasBothTypeInLast7Days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 66.66 | 33.33 | 0 |

How could I do that?

I'm using a PostgreSQL 11.x

Comment: Yes it is possible !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way:

```
select count(*) filter (where xt = 'A' and xt = mt) * 100.0 / count(*) typeA
     , count(*) filter (where xt = 'B' and xt = mt) * 100.0 / count(*) typeB
     , count(*) filter (where xt <> mt) * 100.0 / count(*) BothTypes
from (
  select origin, max(type) xt , min(type) mt
  from data
  where date >  now() - interval '7 days'
  group by origin
 ) t
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8af090e1cbbf781b24c21a766033c652)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `cte`:

```sql
with cte as (
   select r.origin, r.type, count(*) c from records r where r.date >= now() - interval '7 day' group by r.origin, r.type
),
cte1 as (
   select c.origin, count(distinct c.type) c1 from cte c group by c.origin
)
select sum(case when c.type = 'A' then 1 end)/cast((select count(*) from cte) as float), 
   sum(case when c.type = 'B' then 1 end)/cast((select count(*) from cte) as float),
   (select count(*) from cte1 c1 where c1.c1 = (select count(distinct c3.type) from records c3))/((select count(*) from cte) as float)
from cte c
```